# dropdown list in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to display values to drop down list from Database.
For that in my controller class i did the following to get the values from db and its getting properly.

```
 @value = Message.find(:all)

<Message ID: 14448, SlNo: 609">, #<Message ID: 14448, SlNo: 610">
```

How can i display the  SlNo values to drop down list.Here is the code am using and getting error!I don't know how to set values inside a collection_select.Please help me!!

```
<% @value.each do |d| %>
<%=collection_select(:value, :id, @value, :id, { selected: params.fetch(:value, {})[:id].to_i, :prompt => "-Select a device" }) %>
<% end %>
```

Table names getting

```
["UniqueDeviceID", "SlNo"]
```

Model

```
class MessageDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  set_table_name 'DeviceDetails'
set_primary_key 'SlNo'
end
```

Comment: is that table names of column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
<% @value.each do |d| %>
  <%=collection_select(:value, :id, @value, :id, { selected: params.fetch(:device, {})[:id].to_i, :prompt => "-Select a device" }) %>
<% end %>
```

use

```
<%= collection_select :value, :id, @value, :id, :S1No, { selected: params.fetch(:device, {})[:id].to_i, :prompt => "-Select a device" } %>
```

UPDATE: explanations for passed parameters

- :value = a symbol representation of the record you want to update, it may also not be an instance record but just a symbol that will be used in the naming convention of the select tag
- :id    = the column that you wish to update
- @value = the collection to show the choices
- :id    = the method you want to use that will be passed as the value of the selected value
- :S1No  = the method that will be used as the label for the options of the select tag

Comment: getting erroR!!!!!!!!syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...ompt => "-Select a device" }) );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
...                               ^

Comment: sorry there's an extra `)` at the end of `collection_select`

Comment: here is the code am using getting the same error :-(................<%= collection_select :value, :id, @value, :id, :S1No, { selected: params.fetch(:value, {})[:id].to_i, :prompt => "-Select a device" }) %>

Comment: yeah like i said, there's an extra `)` at the end which causes the error.

Comment: undefined method `S1No' for #<Device:0x41790c0> is getting

Comment: try replacing `:S1No` with `:SlNo`. i manually typed that assuming that it's a 1 not an l :D

Comment: answer is perfect, i read the question wrong, deleting mine :)

Comment: undefined method id is getting..iam using ms sql server not mysql.so auto generated id is not in the table.so what will i place instead of id

Comment: i've updated my answer with an explanation of what each parameter means.  you should be able to figure out what you want to use of `:id`

Comment: im sorry,ur answer is correct,but i Don't know still iam getting error- undefined method `SlNo' for #<Array:0x4c9dd48>.:-(

Comment: one more thing,i am feting the table details from a remote machine. DB is not in my system.

Comment: class CreateMessageDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :message_details do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
its is my 20130307092544_create_message_details.rb

Comment: you have to take note of the column_names of your tables.  for example, if you have a messages table and use the Message model for it, you can get a list of the columns names by calling Message.column_names.  Then you can access the values in these column names by finding a message then calling message.id (if you have an id column)

Comment: yes i input the colum names i have.it contains SlNo.but  in collection_select undefined method `SlNo' is showing

Comment: can you create a gist that shows the column names of the model you're trying to access, the controller code and the view that you're using.

Comment: No i did not create the list of column names.is it necessary???please dont feel bad.actually am new to rails.

Answer (score 1):

```
# START
f.collection_select :id, Message.all(:order => "name"), :id, :name, :include_blank => true
# END
```

OR

```
# START
messages_arr = []    
messages = Message.all(:order => "name")
messages.each do |msg|
 messages_arr << [msg.name, msg.id]
end
f.select(:id, options_for_select(messages_arr), {:include_blank => 'Include All'}, {:class=>"span12"})
# END
```